# Compare CSV with arrays with two columns of another CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I have two CSVs. CSV1 consists of 3 columns: *Name, Username, MainGroup*; CSV2 consist of 4  columns: *Name, Username, Department, Division*. Both CSVs sort by *Name* column.

I need to compare data from these two CVS, specifically *Department* and *Division* from CVS2 with *MainGroup* from CSV1. And then export result into a CVS-file, what will contain *Name, Username, MatchedGroup*. So in 3rd column of result CVS I would like to keep the result of comparing of *Department* and *Division* with column *MainGroup*. I.e. if a value from *Department* or *Division* columns from CVS2 matches with a value from *MainGroup* column from CSV1, then keep in result the matched value.

Yup, I can use `Compare-Object` cmdlet, but it is hard to imagine loop that I need to compare values and get a result. Moreover, *MainGroup* column could has a few values divided by comma, so that is why I have to compare columns and keep the one that will match or keep in result original value from *MainGroup* column if *Department* and *Division* will be empty.

Example of CSV1:

| Name | UserName | MainGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dave Davidson | Dave.D | NCR |
| Hugo Lotson | Hugo.L | Legion |
| Umi Ugo | Umi | CBA |
| Rendal Echo | Rendal.E | NCR,CBA |

Example of CVS2:

| Name | UserName | Department | Division |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dave Davidson | Dave.D | NCR |  |
| Hugo Lotson | Hugo.L | Legion | NCR |
| Umi Ugo | Umi |  |  |
| Rendal Echo | Rendal.E |  | Legion |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's undoubtedly a much cleaner, nicer way of doing this with less code - however I usually find it easier to create a class to populate the results of CSV comparisons, as you get some easier output for a CSV this way.

This could be simplified, but hopefully this will help explain the loop/flow a bit. Copy this into a file (e.g; `Comapre-Csv.ps1`), then run it like so;

`.\Compare-Csv.ps1 -SourceCsv .\csv_1.csv -ComparisonCsv .\csv_2.csv -ExportPath .\result.csv`

**Script:**

```
param (
    [string]
    $SourceCsv,
    [string]
    $ComparisonCsv,
    [string]
    $ExportPath
)
# Import both CSV's
$source = Import-Csv $SourceCsv
$comparison = Import-Csv $ComparisonCsv

# Create a class/array for easier CSV export
class ResultLine {
    [string]$Name
    [string]$UserName
    [string]$MainGroup
}
[ResultLine[]]$results = @()

foreach($sourceRow in $source) {
    # Find row in the comparison CSV by filtering to UserName
    $comparisonRow = $comparison | Where-Object -Property UserName -eq $sourceRow.UserName
    if($comparisonRow) {
        Write-Host "Comparing [$($sourceRow.UserName)] to [$($comparisonRow.UserName)]"
        
        # default to MainGroup - will be be overwritten if found in comparison
        [string]$mainGroup = $sourceRow.MainGroup

        # Check the department/division values from the comaprison row
        if(($comparisonRow.Department) -and ($comparisonRow.Division)) {
            # If the department & division are the same, just use the department
            if($comparisonRow.Department -eq $comparisonRow.Division) {
                $mainGroup = $comparisonRow.Department
            } else {
                $mainGroup = "$($comparisonRow.Department),$($comparisonRow.Division)"
            }
        }
        elseif($comparisonRow.Department) {
            $mainGroup = $comparisonRow.Department
        }
        elseif($comparisonRow.Division) {
            $mainGroup = $comparisonRow.Division
        }

        # Store the result
        $results += [ResultLine]@{
            Name = $sourceRow.Name
            UserName = $sourceRow.UserName
            MainGroup = $mainGroup
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "[$($sourceRow.UserName)] not found in [$ComparisonCsv]" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}

# Export CSV
$results | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Like I said, there's much shorter, cleaner ways - but hopefully this helps. Keep in mind that if `UserName` *isn't* in the Source, but *is* in the destination, this script won't handle that.

Comment: Thank you! It is super cool and works like a charm. But I would like to know if I could keep only one value in the result

Comment: Yep, have a look at the chain of `if` statements - that's where it's deterring what value takes priority for `MainGroup` - if you let me know what you'd  like the logic to be, I can update the script for you. For `Hugo Lotson`, who has two values in `department` and `division`, which value would you like to keep?

Comment: I mean that now, as I understood, if MainGroup value is equal both to Department and Division, then it doubles in result value. So, I suppose, loop should be stopped in case if MainGroup value is equal to Department as first one in row 

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - correct me if I'm wrong here; if `Department` and `Division` both have the same value (e.g; `Legion`) - then the result will be `Legion,Legion` - so we you just want to stop that duplication/concatenation if the values are equal to each other?

Comment: If I've made the correct assumption there, try again with the updated script.